# Kafka SQL Lenses query to search payload that has a field

Tags: apache-kafka, lenses

I would like to query my kafka payload in lenses(3.2) to search the payload and select  the payload that have a specific field.

I understand that there is a tabular view but I want to search all the data that exists in the topic.

i have searched the documentation (https://docs.lenses.io/2.1/lenses-sql/where.html#exists-function) and have found the EXISTS function but it does not seem to work

queries tried -

```
USE `kafka`;
SELECT * FROM topic_name where EXISTS(field_name)
```

Thank you for helping me.